# Logger system - using levels c++

Tags: c++, oop, logging, wrapper, ostream

How can I use a function from (Wrap ostream in class and templatize << operator)

I want to use SEVERITY levels for the logger and each level can take any number of msg/ elements

This class accept any number for elements in the object but I need it also for each function in the class
ex:

```
ClassName ClassObject(&std::cout)
ClassObject.info() << "test msg" << 5 << 10 << endl;
```

this is my class

```
class logger {

private:
    ostream * str;

public:

    logger( ostream* str_v) : str(str_v) {}

    template <class T>
    logger& operator<<(T&& x) {
        *str << std::forward<T>(x);
        return *this;
    }

    logger& operator<<(ostream& (*manip)(ostream&)) {
        *str << manip;
        return *this;
    }

    void info(){
        cout <<"hello world"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){

   logger l(&std::cout);
    l << 5 << std::string(" test")<<endl;
   //I want to use info like that
   l.info() << "print anything" << 5 << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Let `info()` write to `*str` and return a reference to `*this`?

Comment: By the way, why don't you use references instead of pointers to the stream?

Comment: Back to the problem at hand, the way I personally do it is to have a second helper-class which is returned by the severity/level function. This helper-class have the stream overload functions, and it also writes a newline and flushes the stream on destruction. Then the output is guaranteed to end with a newline and actually be written. No need to use `endl` in the logging "call".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry but I'm new to c++ can you give me some examples to be more clear

Comment: Could you elaborate on the desired effects of writing to different log levels? Assuming there's a `debug` log level what's the expected result of `log.info() << x << endl;` compared to `log.debug() << x << endl;`? Could you add the desired output of the `main` function in your code to the question?

Comment: @fabian I will use spdlog library so I need to split each function to call spdlog library with different levels

Comment: That gets me a bit confused. A short look at the spdlog github page does not indicate any way of using stream operators. (Haven't looked too deep btw.) Is `l.info() << "print anything" << 5 << endl;` achieve the same effect as `spdlog::info("print anything6\n");`?

Comment: @fabian I'm trying to use spdlog in the info function that in the my class, so it not finished yet but I'm trying ti implement this interface for spdlog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a very simple solution, let `info()` write to `*str` and return a reference to `*this`:

```
logger& info()
{
    *str << "info - ";
    return *this;
}
```

Then is can be used as you wish:

```
l.info() << "print anything" << 5 << endl;
```

The above should print

```
info - print anything 5
```